# Continuous borders through multiple blocks of a blockarray

Tags: matrices, border, blkarray

I have this rather complicated matrix I'm trying to make with the `blkarray` package.

```
\begin{figure}
\aboverulesep=0pt \belowrulesep=0pt
\center
    \begin{blockarray}{cccccccccccc}
      & $e_1$ & $e_2$ & $\dots$ & $e_j$ & $\ldots$ & $e_n$ & $e'_1$ & $e'_2$ & $\ldots$ & $e'_j$ & f \\
      \cmidrule{2-11}
    \begin{block}{c[cccccc|cccc|c]}
          & & & & & & & & & & & $0$ \\
          & & & $B$ & & & & & & $C$ & & $0$ \\
          & & & & & & & & & & & $\vdots$ \\
          & & & & & & & & & & & $0$ \\
      \cmidrule(l){2-11}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{c[ccccccccccc]}
         $r_1$ & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & & & & $1$ \\
         $r_2$ & & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & & & $1$ \\
         $\vdots$ & & & $\ddots$ & & & & & & $\ddots$ & & $\vdots$ \\
         $r_j$ & & & & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & $1$ \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{figure}
```

What I want is for the matrix to be bordered with a bracket, where the columns and some of the rows have labels outside the bracket. The code I've pasted won't work for that because the `[`s and `]`s in the block declarations only apply to that block, so the brackets get broken in the middle. If I replace them with `|`, it looks continuous at least, but then it doesn't quite look like a border.

How can I get continuous borders with the labels outside them? The above code renders this, but I want just a single pair of brackets.

[image: matrix that the above code renders]

Comment: This is not very clear. Could you post an image showing what you'd like to have?

Comment: Do you mean you want a unique bracket on each side?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question to include the render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `bigdelim` which comes with `multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray, bigdelim, booktabs}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
\aboverulesep=0pt \belowrulesep=0pt
\centering
   $ \begin{array}{c@{}c@{}*{6}{c}|*{4}{c}|c@{}c}
      & & e_1 & e_2 & \dots & e_j & \ldots & e_n & e'_1 & e'_2 & \ldots & \mc{e'_j }& \mathrm{f} \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
         & \ldelim [{9}{*}& & & & & & & & & & & 0 & \rdelim ]{9}{*}\\
          & & & & B & & & & & & C & & 0 \\
           & & & & & & & & & & & & \vdots \\
          & & & & & & & & & & & & 0 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
         r_1 & & 1 & & & & &\mc{} & 1 & & &\mc{} & 1 \\
         r_2 & & 1 & & & & &\mc{} & 1 & &\mc{} & \mc{} & 1\\
         \vdots & & & & \ddots & & &\mc{} & & & \ddots &\mc{} & \vdots \\
         r_j & & & & & 1 & &\mc{} & & & & \mc{1}& 1
    \end{array} $
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.11 of 2021-02-22).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,left-margin=7pt,xdots/shorten=4pt]
\rule[-7pt]{0pt}{7pt}
       & e_1 & e_1 & \Ldots & e_j & \Ldots & e_n & e_1' & e_2' & \Ldots & e_j' \\
       & \Block{4-6}{B}
             &     &        &     &        &     & \Block{4-4}{C}
                                                        &     &        &      & 0 \\
       &     &     &        &     &        &     &      &     &        &      & 0 \\
       &     &     &        &     &        &     &      &     &        &      & \Vdots \\
       &     &     &        &     &        &     &      &     &        &      & 0 \\\noalign{\vskip1mm}
r_1    & 1   &     &        &     &        &     & 1    &     &        &      & 1 \\
r_2    &     & 1   &        &     &        &     &      & 1   &        &      & 1 \\
\Vdots &     &     & \Ddots &     &        &     &      &     & \Ddots &      & \Vdots \\
r_j    &     &     &        & 1   &        &     &      &     &        & 1    & 1
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (5-|1) -| (1-|11) (1-|7) -- (5-|7) ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

Just another flavor. Only `blkarray`. I did not alter your code, so `B` and `C` are not properly centered.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.8pt}

\begin{figure}

    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{3ex}}ccccccc   @{\hspace{2.5ex}}cccc @{\hspace{3ex}}c}
        & $e_1$ & $e_2$ & $\dots$ & $e_j$ & $\ldots$ & $e_n$ & $e'_1$ & $e'_2$ & $\ldots$ & $e'_j$ & f \\
    \end{tabular}
    
    \begin{blockarray}{c @{\hspace{1ex}}[ ccccccc  cccc@{} ]}
        \begin{block*}{ccccccc|cccc|c}
            & & & & & & & & & & & $0$ \\
            & & & $B$ & & & & & & $C$ & & $0$ \\
            & & & & & & & & & & & $\vdots$ \\
            & & & & & & & & & & & $0$ \\
            \cline{2-11}
        \end{block*}
        \begin{block*}{cccccccccccc}
            $r_1$ & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & & & & $1$ \\
            $r_2$ & & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & & & $1$ \\
            $\vdots$ & & & $\ddots$ & & & & & & $\ddots$ & & $\vdots$ \\
            $r_j$ & & & & $1$ & & & & & & $1$ & $1$ \\
        \end{block*}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document
```